# How do I enforce process without support from management or peers?

Tags: project-management, process

How do I say **yes** to "Do I really have to file a ticket ?" without support from management or even QA team ?

I'm a team lead for a software development team. I have a product manager that always spread his documentation/specifications everywhere: on calls, on slack channels, on slack direct messages, (avoids emails) .. sometimes in Jira.

I've insisted on everything being filed in Jira, I've explained the advantages of being able to track issues, on the fact that Jira is accessible to the whole team and I don't have to repeat myself explaining, nothing seems to register with this guy.

I escalated this issue to the manager sponsoring this project and got a "let's not make this a science project", to my normal manager who said that we need to insist on process, but doesn't actually get involved. I asked the QA team to insist on Jira tickets, they say yes, but do nothing (either because they are not involved when the the request is made, or because when they are asked to test, it's already to late).

Also, this project is growing exponentially, in terms of users, and I expect that the situation will get worse, while now it's manageable to have them spread everywhere, at some point this will no longer be the case.

I have other projects that I'm developing that are working fine, I have a team that I love and get along nicely, and I can't refuse this project. I'm really at the end of my rope, and contemplating leaving the company, but I would rather not do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I say yes to "Do I really have to file a ticket ?" without
> support from management or even QA team ?

In general, you don't.

I've had some success in the past by saying something more along the lines of "The process requires a ticket first. Let me help you file one." And then my team only worked from the ticket.

It tended to change the culture over time, although not completely. Over time management started to expect people to use the process. I was running QA, so that part was never an issue.

Answer (score 10):

1. **You could just let it fail.** Having documentation and specifications everywhere is inevitably going to lead to some major missed items in terms of work to be done. I was on a project with a PM who did this and a couple weeks of him not seeing key features built that he wanted to be built convinced him to use our Jira equivalent. Same thing happened with a business analyst on another project I was on. He would just say what he wanted changed in various reviews and demos, but maybe half of it was worked on. That convinced him of the need for project task and requirement tracking.
2. **If major errors aren't already happening, it may not matter.** I am curious how this did not self resolve. Usually the person asking for the work gets annoyed when that work is not done and this gives you an opportunity to point to why. Unless some developer is very diligent in covering for them, it should have already happened.  May it really not matter if this project is done well? This was an interesting realization about the workplace when I graduated. Excellence is frequently irrelevant.

Comment: Work gets done, but usually on my expense. I end up doing his job and mine.

Comment: @mostafawornout so you see why the manager has no reason to believe this is a problem right?

Answer (score 2):

> my normal manager who said that we need to insist on process, but doesn't actually get involved.

Your manager doesn't need to get involved, they told you to insist on process.  That means you don't work on items that don't have a Jira ticket.

Product Manager via memo left on your chair, "hey I sent you a teams message, please fix this"

You via phone or in person, "I need a Jira entered before I can work on an issue"

Product Manager, "@!#$% &^#@#"

You, "You need to take this up with my manager, who instructed me to insist on process."

Then you live with the results.  Your manager will either cave to the PM when the PM calls them or will say,"yes, that's the process, please follow it."  If they cave, then the system will continue to be a mess, and you will either deal with the mess or find a new place to work.  If they enforce the process, your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

> normal manager who said that we need to insist on process

So long as he can just agree and you go away that's the route of least resistance.

Be persistent. It's his job to get involved. Involve him, ask him for solution strategies, make him a part of it. When he starts feeling responsible he will take action.